Movie about a man that reincarnates as a dog
This one is really killing me, as I have been searching for years and can't find any info anywhere (IMDB, Google) and I would love to re-watch it.
I watched this film in an international film festival years ago (between 2001 and 2004, can't remember the exact date).
I remember that it was about a man that dies and reincarnates as a dog. The story follows the dog's life from that point onward. There was no goofy-dog-that-talks, it was sort of a drama, there was a narrator (possibly the dog's thoughts). And I'm very sure the name of the dog was Baal (maybe with a different spelling), because that was the name of the film.
The film was subtitled, because it was foreign (I remember it was a very strange language to me, it was not Korean or Japanese for sure, maybe Pakistan or Iran). 
Anybody can give me any clue what's the actual name of the movie and where could I find it?

Apart from Fluke, even Oh! Heavenly Dog and Quigley have similar storylines, although none of these are foreign movies.

those are comedies

Was it feature-length?

@Walt yes, although I'm not sure about the exact lenght

OK, the plot is kind of in reverse, but this might be it: 1998 drama State of Dogs.

Set in Mongolia's capital city, Ulan Bator, the film combines documentary elements with fictional elements in the fragmented, impressionistic and dreamlike story of Baasar, a dog who dies early in the movie [...] According to Mongolian legend, a dog (who is prepared) may be reincarnated in its next life as a human, after roaming free for as long as he wants. Baasar roams the memory of his life, uninterested in advancing to a human life.

Baasar's journey is narrated by a man. The film is in Mongolian, which I guess could be mistaken for Persian, and has been shown in many festivals. The entire movie is available on Youtube.

Wow, my memory really sucks... Yes, that's the movie! It is kinda the opposite of everything that's on my question, glad you could figure it out!

The movie that I believe that you are talking about is called Dean spanley it has Peter O'Toole in it and Sam Neill. The plot from wiki:

In the very early 1900s, Henslowe Fisk lives beholden to his father, the difficult Horatio Fisk. The Fisk family has suffered first the loss of its younger son, Harrington Fisk (Xavier Horan), killed in the Second Anglo-Boer War, shortly followed by the death of Horatio's wife. Fisk Senior is looked after by his housekeeper Mrs Brimley (Judy Parfitt) who has lost her husband. Fisk Junior reluctantly visits his father every Thursday.
One day, trying to entertain his father, Fisk Junior brings him to a lecture by a visiting swami (Art Malik) about the transmigration of souls. The lecture is also attended by the new local clergyman, Dean Spanley (Sam Neill).
Later the same day Fisk Junior encounters the Dean at his father's
  club. A chance third meeting leads to an introduction. Fisk Junior,
  initially intrigued by the Dean's oddly open-minded views on
  reincarnation, is prompted to look beyond the Dean's appearance (that
  of an affable, rather bland clergyman) by his weakness for certain
  peculiar sensations produced by Hungarian Imperial Tokay wine, which
  leads him into a dreamlike state. Working with his clever friend
  Wrather (Bryan Brown), an Australian "conveyancer", Fisk secures a
  batch of Tokay and the two entertain the Dean, who acts ever more
  strangely, starting to reveal memories of his previous life — as a
  Welsh Spaniel. These memories are acute and convincing, including rich
  feelings around food and communication with other canines, a deep
  distaste for cats and pigs, and the joy of serving his master. As the
  story unfolds, Fisk Junior comes to understand his father's background
  better and the two draw closer. There is a sub-plot concerning Fisk
  Senior's childhood that receives an unexpected resolution forming the
  climax of the story.

It was released in 2008

nope. I already accepted another answer, the movie is "State of Dog". Not a western production - read the question
