Man That Acts Like A Dog
*This movie is NOT 'Walk Like A Man' starring Howie Mandel.
I watched a movie a while back, I honestly can't even remember what year but most likely 2000-2005 when I saw it. Movie was in English, took place in America, color picture, good quality, and couldn't have been released earlier than 80s or later than 2005. I know, wide time range but just giving my best prediction. Here's what I remember from it.
It was a movie where a woman with a dog (I don't remember what kind of dog) happen to be in  fire either in their home or in a building and she thought they were going to die but she survives. I'm not sure if the dog dies or not in that fire but he leaves her life; she never sees him again. I didn't actually see the part about the fire but I know it happened because she talks about it how it happened in the movie. So in the beginning of the movie (which I didn't watch) that scene either showed or her memories of it showed.
She has a male friend (not sure if he is her boyfriend) and then somehow they meet this man who has the spirit of a dog in him. He acts like a dog, pees like a dog, etc but he's a human man. They become friends with him and the woman doesn't know it is actually her dog reincarnated as that man. I'm pretty sure the other guy, her friend, knows it is though. 
There also might be another character or two that are friends with them but I have only really seen the middle towards the end of the movie, and don't really remember much.
At a point in the movie, the two men tell the woman that the one guy is actually her dog and when she doesn't believe them, he proves it by telling her what she whispered to him when they were in the fire, which was "I love you". That is when she believes it is him; her dog as a human man. 
And I also remember towards the end of the movie, the man that was her dog somehow doesn't have the spirit of her dog anymore in him and starts acting like a regular guy. The woman and her friend knew that was going to happen, I don't remember how but they knew there would come a time very soon where he would be a regular human man again. It happened when he was on a couch in someone's living room. The friend petted his head as he normally did, well because he was like a dog, and the guy says something like "woah, watch it" and pushes his hand away. That's when they realized the time of him being a dog was up.
I don't remember how it happened in the first place or what happened to her dog or why there was a timer on the guy being her dog, or how the two even met the dog guy but that is probably because I didn't watch the beginning of the movie.
It is a funny movie if I remember correctly, definitely not scary, or a thriller/horror etc. And yes, it was a movie, not a show. I've been searching and racking my brain on the name of this movie for years, but it's been very difficult since I don't remember the year it came out, any of the actors, or really the entire detailed plot from beginning to end. Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/32296/movie-about-a-man-that-reincarnates-as-a-dog ?

Ghost Dog:  A Detective Tale. 2003
Took me and my wife forever to find the name of it.

Are you @des ... the person who asked the question?

In any case, you might want to elaborate in which way this fits the details from the question in order to flesh out this answer a little more.

OMG IT IS. Wow. It has taken me years to find the name of this movie. You and your wife are amazing. Many many thanks! Too bad I'm having such a terrible time trying to find this movie to watch it with the kids. Can't find where to buy the movie anywhere! However thank you again! :D

It could be Didier, a French movie released in 1997. I am not sure about the "I love you" part, but it's definitely about a dog turned into a man.

Jean-Pierre, a frazzled sport agent, has better things to do than to
  look after his friend's labrador Didier. An amazing discovery will
  lead him off on an amazing adventure


Didier is a good soccer player. That's a lot about the movie that could help to identify it.

No, sorry, it's a movie in English.

Dean Spanley from 2008?
This was an Edwardian movie, quite nice, with Sam Neill.

The most remarkable of all of the movie's components is its plot,
  which counteracts against central character Fisk Senior's (Peter
  O'Toole) callous, very much close-minded approach to life. Going from
  happenstance to coincidence and then closely followed by an almost
  prophetic like relationship, Fisk's son strikes up an interesting bond
  with the local Dean (Sam Neill), who when under the modest influence
  of the rarest of wines, recalls his past life as a canine. From here
  on in the feature exposes its most bizarre roots, showcasing a
  character and story that often perplexes more than intrigues, but
  amuses all the same. It's certainly an interesting, and for the most
  part engaging narrative, but for all intents and purposes always feels
  like second batter to much firmer and more developed elements. This,
  along with a somewhat overdone conclusion forms what are perhaps the
  movie's only two major faults, but even then such moments are not
  without their inherent charm and significance to the remainder of the
  feature.


You might want to elaborate in which way this movie fits to the details from the question in order to flesh out the answer a little more.

There was a 1951 movie entitled "You Never Can Tell" (Also known as "You Never Know) starring Dick Powell:

An ex-police/army dog (German Shepherd), named Rex inherits a fortune from an eccentric millionaire. But someone poisons him for his fortune, and he gets to go back to earth as a human detective to bring his killer to justice, and protect the girl who used to look after him. 


You might want to elaborate in which way this movie fits to the details from the question in order to flesh out the answer a little more.
